# How to filter resultset rows by comparing malformed date string and today's date?

Tags: php, mysql, date, filtering, date-formatting

I have a VARCHAR column in my mysql database that stores dates with commas rather than hyphens.

I want to fetch some data by comparing these dates against the current date. To get the current date, I am using the php5 method `date("Y,m,d");` and declaring it as `$date;`

If the current date is less than a given row's date, then I want to retrieve it otherwise omit it from the resultset.

Here is my code

```
$date=date("Y,m,d"); //current date to check if expiry date is valid or not
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=******;dbname=******", $username, "******");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "select id, discount, expirydate, description, logouploader from table WHERE expirydate>= ? LIMIT 10";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(array($date));
    foreach($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
        echo $row['expirydate'];
    }  
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

My code does not compare dates; it fetches all rows even though it was supposed to leave those records which are less than `$date;` // current date

How can I filter my resultset to only return rows which are not yet expired?

Comment: what is the format of the dates on your server

Comment: i am storing it as varchar and format is YYYYMMDD means for example 2018,04,15

Comment: Do you have comma in your database?

Comment: yes i have comma same as "Y,m,d" like 2018,04,27(example)

Comment: does hosting server effect this time? i have server in australia and i am in canada.

Comment: Try to define the timezone before to use `date()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: @haider, can you show sample of your query results? With the value of $date that you were comparing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the bad news**:  Your code is suffering from the ramifications of bad database design.  If you are storing date values, never store them in anything other than a date-type column.

**Here is the good news**: Even if you don't repair your database structure (and you really, really should), you don't need any php to get your query working.  In fact, you don't even need to employ a prepared statement because there are no variables to include.

Code: ([SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cddc1c/1))

```
SELECT discount,
       description,
       logouploader,
       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(expirydate, '%Y,%m,%d'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS `reformatted`
FROM `table`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(expirydate, '%Y,%m,%d') >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY expirydate
```

This will yield all rows of discounts that have not yet expired (ordered by date).

You may notice that:

- You don't need to reformat `expirydate` in the `ORDER BY` clause because it is accurately sorted as a string.
- I could have just as easily called upon [REPLACE()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php) instead of [STR_TO_DATE()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php) to format your comma-separated date to hyphen-separated.
- [DATE_FORMAT()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/) will offer you great flexibility in formatting the date in your resultset, so that your php can do less processing.

Answer (score 0):

Use explode to convert your date string to an array and then reassymble your date string.

```
function convertDateString($dateString){

  $dateArray = explode(',', $dateString);

  return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateArray[0] . '-' . $dateArray[1] . '-' . $dateArray[2]));

}


$date= date('Y-m-d'); //current date to check if expiry date is valid or not
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=******;dbname=******", $username, "******");
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = "select id, discount, expirydate, description, logouploader from table WHERE expirydate>= ? LIMIT 10";
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(array($date));
foreach($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

  if(strtotime($date) < strtotime(convertDateString($row['expirydate']))){

    echo $row['expirydate'];


  }else {

    //Do something else;

  }


}

}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
```

Comment: what is the reason for this ? i have date in my db like this 0000,00,00. Does 0000-00-00 compares it with 0000,00,00 ?

Comment: YYYY,MM,DD is not a valid date format.  YYYY-MM-DD is a valid date format.  So we chop up your date string and reform it to a correct one.  Then we convert the date string to a timestamp and compare the values.

Comment: @haider Please make note that I also changed the format of your $date variable to 'Y-m-d'

Comment: it is working fine thanks you but sir my company have 22000 data in their database you are comparing it after fetching. The problem is that it can affect the speed of website i need resolve this issue before fetching. Is there any solution? i am new just started working after graduation i am totally fedup.

Comment: I'm not an expert with optimizing code and the amount of processing steps required to do what you want.  But if I were in your shoes, I would write a query that takes your current dates on the DB and replaces them with their DateTime equivalent values.  Then you could form a query that will return the results that you want.   If I solved your problem please mark as the accepted answer.  Cheers